# Material sidenav does not close

Tags: angular-material

In my Angular project I have a [mat-sidenav](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview) with some routing inside a mat-nav-list.
On small screens, the sidenav has "over" mode with a backdrop but sometimes when I click on a routing element I see that sidenav does not close and loses backdrop as you can see in the video.
This sidenav is generated with material sidenav schematics, here the code:

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav #drawer [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
           [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
           [opened]="(isHandset$ | async) === false"
           fixedInViewport>
     <mat-toolbar class="white">
       <img [attr.src]="'assets/img/logo.png'">
     </mat-toolbar>

     <mat-nav-list>
      <a href="#" mat-list-item (click)="drawer.toggle()" routerLink="dashboard">
        <mat-icon>analytics</mat-icon>
        <div>dashboard</div>
      </a>

      <a href="#" mat-list-item (click)="drawer.toggle()" routerLink="documents">
        <mat-icon>text_snippet</mat-icon>
        <div>documents</div>
      </a>

      <a href="#" mat-list-item (click)="drawer.toggle()" routerLink="eyeExams">
        <img class="mr-2" src="assets/img/eyeexam2.png" width="24px">
        <div>eyeexams</div>
      </a>

      <a href="#" mat-list-item (click)="drawer.toggle()" routerLink="contactLensSupply">
        <mat-icon >visibility</mat-icon>
        <div>contactlenssupply</div>
      </a>
    </mat-nav-list>
   </mat-sidenav>
   <mat-sidenav-content>
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

And this is the property in the component:

```
  isHandset$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver.observe('(max-width: 899px)')
    .pipe(
      map(result => result.matches),
      shareReplay()
    );
```

[image]